# Facebook api 1.0 or 2.0 search by hashtag in public posts

Tags: facebook, api, search, posts, hashtag

Is there a way to get posts by hashtag from facebook api (v1.0 or 2.0). We know that this specific function is deprecated and in version 2.0 does not returns results, in version 1.0 we get some results but we are wondering if there is an alternative method to perform this kind of search. Please, any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There's the Keyword Insights API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights), but it's only available to specific partners of Facebook.

Sadly, there's no alternative to the old public post search (which wasn't really working reliably for hashtags anyway) in v2.0.